# Using useState and UseEffect in this way makes the slider for for the first times but then dosent work

Tags: reactjs, slider

```
const HeroSection = () => {
    const [Change,setChange] = useState(false);
    useEffect(() => {
        setInterval(() => {
            setChange(!Change)
        }, 5000);
        return () => clearInterval();
      }, [Change]);
  



return (
    <HeroContainer>
        <HeroBg>
            <ImageBg src={ Change ? Image1 : Image2 }  />
            
            
        </HeroBg>
    </HeroContainer>
   
)``
```

}

export default HeroSection

react auto slide images works for the first few times then becomes buggy as in fast paced changes of images regardless of the 5 sec interval

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`clearInterval();` does nothing. You need to pass the created interval's ID to `clearInterval` for it to be cleared.

I also don't think the effect hook should have `change` as a dependency unless you use `setTimeout` instead.

```
const [change, setChange] = useState(false);
useEffect(() => {
    const timeoutId = setTimeout(() => {
        setChange(!change)
    }, 5000);
    return () => clearTimeout(timeoutId);
}, [change]);
```

to set a new timeout in the effect callback every time `change` changes.

Or:

```
const [change, setChange] = useState(false);
useEffect(() => {
    const intervalId = setInterval(() => {
        setChange(change => !change)
    }, 5000);
    return () => clearInterval(intervalId);
}, []);
```

to set an interval *only once*, when the component mounts.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I am new to react and was unable to understand the complicated codes used in youtube and other places for this thing so i tried something my way knowing what i knew. Can you help me understand why was this happening? what is the use of that id and clearInterval?

Comment: `setInterval` and `setTimeout` return IDs corresponding to the interval/timeout set - numbers. To clear the interval or timeout, pass those IDs to `clearInterval` or `clearTimeout`.